# How to use two pipes in a row in angular

Tags: angular, pipe

I have a pipe which transform numbers into strings.

```
Import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'nomeMesPipe',
})

export class NomeMesPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any): string {
    if (value) {
      switch (
        value // Converte o numero em nome do mês
      ) {
        case 0:
          value = 'Janeiro';
          break;
        case 1:
          value = 'Fevereiro';
          break;
        case 2:
          value = 'Março';
          break;
        case 3:
          value = 'Abril';
          break;
        case 4:
          value = 'Maio';
          break;
        case 5:
          value = 'Junho';
          break;
        case 6:
          value = 'Julho';
          break;
        case 7:
          value = 'Agosto';
          break;
        case 8:
          value = 'Setembro';
          break;
        case 9:
          value = 'Outubro';
          break;
        case 10:
          value = 'Novembro';
          break;
        case 11:
          value = 'Dezembro';
          break;
      }
      return value;
    }
    return '';
  }
}
```

Then I have a date, which split into days, month, and years, using date pipes.
just like this:

```
{{data.dataDeAceite | date:'dd'}} // 15
{{data.dataDeAceite | date: 'M'  }} //6
{{data.dataDeAceite | date:'yyyy'}} //2020
```

I want to return a string according to the month number, so I tried:

```
{{ data.dataDeAceite | date: 'M'| nomeMesPipe }}
```

But it didn't work.

How to return the month name, in portuguese, using pipes?

Comment: Why don't you use `{{ data.dataDeAceite | date: 'MMMM' }}`? It should return the month name out of the box.

Comment: Its returns in english, and I need in portuguese, that's why I created the pipe.

Comment: Changing the locale is not enough?

Comment: You don't need a custom pipe for that. Take a look in this link and you'll be setup for Portuguese: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20197#issuecomment-361097171

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because angular date pipe will return value as string if you convert string to number inside custom pipe it will work.

**Try this:**

```
 transform(value: any): string {
    if (value) {
      switch (
        parseFloat(value) 
      ) {
        case 0:
          value = 'Janeiro';
          break;
        case 1:
          value = 'Fevereiro';
          break;
        case 2:
          value = 'Março';
          break;
        case 3:
          value = 'Abril';
          break;
        case 4:
          value = 'Maio';
          break;
        case 5:
          value = 'Junho';
          break;
        case 6:
          value = 'Julho';
          break;
        case 7:
          value = 'Agosto';
          break;
        case 8:
          value = 'Setembro';
          break;
        case 9:
          value = 'Outubro';
          break;
        case 10:
          value = 'Novembro';
          break;
        case 11:
          value = 'Dezembro';
          break;
      }
      return value;
    }
    return '';
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The Angular DatePipe returns a string, not a number. Your switch case checks for numbers. So change your cases to a string or value to string.

And another hint: Date didn't start with 0 (so june is 6, not 5):

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'nomeMes'
})
export class NomeMesPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any): string {
    if (value && !isNaN(value)) {
      value = +value;
      switch (
        value // Converte o numero em nome do mês
      ) {
        case 1:
          value = 'Janeiro';
          break;
        case 2:
          value = 'Fevereiro';
          break;
        case 3:
          value = 'Março';
          break;
        case 4:
          value = 'Abril';
          break;
        case 5:
          value = 'Maio';
          break;
        case 6:
          value = 'Junho';
          break;
        case 7:
          value = 'Julho';
          break;
        case 8:
          value = 'Agosto';
          break;
        case 9:
          value = 'Setembro';
          break;
        case 10:
          value = 'Outubro';
          break;
        case 11:
          value = 'Novembro';
          break;
        case 12:
          value = 'Dezembro';
          break;
      }
      return value;
    }
  }

}
```